# Print every x the word Plof

Tags: java

I want to have my program write the word "plof" every time the plof variable is dividable.
So: let's say user input is for variable plof = 3
I want to have written: 1 2 3 plof 4 5 6 plof 7 8 9 plof

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner invoer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Wat is het \"plof\" getal? (2..9)");
    int plof = invoer.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Tot en met welk getal moet ik tellen?");
    int telGetal = invoer.nextInt();

    for(int i=0; i<= telGetal; i++) {
        System.out.print(" "+i);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the `%` operator in Java does?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use if statement and '%' operator to check if it is appropriate moment to print the line separator.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner invoer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Wat is het \"plof\" getal? (2..9)");
    int plof = invoer.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Tot en met welk getal moet ik tellen?");
    int telGetal = invoer.nextInt();

    for(int i=1; i<= telGetal; i++) {
        System.out.print(" "+i);
        if (i%plof == 0)
            System.out.print('\n');
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```